# Installing java 7 and 8 on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I have installed java 8 onn ubuntu. But now when i want to install 
java 7 its giving me error. Bascially I will be switching from 7 to 8 or vice versa. Is it that I have to uninstall 8 first and then instal 7 and 8 in line.
I am using ubuntu 16.04

the commands i used are as follows

sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update

JDK 7

sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer

download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Reason is Installers have been moved http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html

Answer (score 0):

**to install java 7 :**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Apt-get won't overwrite the existing java versions.

To switch between installed java versions, use the update-java-alternatives command.

List all java versions :

```
update-java-alternatives --list
```

Set java version as default (needs root permissions):

```
sudo update-java-alternatives --set /path/to/java/version
```

..where /path/to/java/version is one of those listed by the previous command (e.g. /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64).

Comment: I have tried this still m getting error. My java 8 in installed already but cant install java 7.
I am getting error
download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer

Comment: can you try :  sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer* 

sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer

sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*java* 

sudo apt-get update 

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java 

sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer

Comment: I got the issue i need to install java 8 first. cause once if u setup up 8 you cant setup 7. So first you setup java 7 and then you setup java 8.